# Rotating textures when using glDrawTexiOES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I created a little texture drawing class from observing the LabelMaker example in the Android SDK.

One thing I can't find however is how to rotate textures drawn with glDrawTexiOES.

is it possible? I've just tried glRotatef but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GL_OES_draw_texture skips any transformations, it's drawn directly as a screen space rectangle, you would need to use texture mapped quads to draw them rotated.